# Javascript answer undefined

Tags: javascript, function, firefox, undefined

Using the following code works in all browsers, but in Firefox it gives the error "TypeError: answer is undefined quiz.js:13"

```
function getAnswer() {
var answer = window.event,
    btn = answer.target || answer.srcElement;
return btn.id;
}
```

In my full code line 13 is

```
btn = answer.target || answer.srcElement;
```

I'm using this piece of code to check which button is pressed.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`window.event` only works in IE. For other browsers, the event is passed as the argument to the handler.

Since this is not your handler of the event, you will have to do this in the actual handler and pass that information to your `getAnswer` function instead of using the global `window.event`

```
function getAnswer(e) {
    var btn = e.target || e.srcElement;
    return btn.id;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(getAnswer(e));
 });
```

Or if using the HTML attribute, you have to pass it from the HTML.

```
<p onclick="alert(getAnswer(event))"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm getting the same error in Firefox:

TypeError: event is undefined

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I need to create a variable with the outcome, how would I go about doing this? The following gives undefined "event" in Firefox, but it does output the ID: var answerInput = getAnswer(event);

Comment: @user3621590 Please post the function (in your answer, not as a comment) that is calling `getAnswer`. The trick is that you have to pass the event object all they way from the event handler down to your `getAnswer`. In the event handler, you get a handle to the event by declaring your handler to take an `event` argument, and by calling `event = event || window.event` and passing that down to `getAnswer(event)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

Firefox does not have a `window.event` but rather uses an event object passed in.  (To the best of my knowledge, this code should not work under Chrome either.)

```
function getAnswer(event) {
  var answer = event || window.event,

  // Added the `var` here.
  var btn = answer.target || answer.srcElement;
  return btn.id;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It does actually work in chrome and all other browsers except Firefox. Adding var does not fix it for me.

Comment: The important part is function getAnswer(>>>>event<<<<) the even parameter. Not the var!